# SQLite android count by name

Tags: android, sqlite

I have one table History.

History table has 3 columns

```
ID   |  timestamp   | imageName
```

I need to count all images where name is like name which i forward from my app

example

```
1 | 12.12.2019 | 8801

2 | 11.11.2019 | 8802

3 | 13.1.2019  | 8802

4 | 1.2.2015   | 8801

5 | 7.8.2019   | 8801
```

i need result like this

```
Image name|  number of images

8801  | 3

8802  | 2
```

...

I need to count it by forwarded variable `imageName`.

This is what i have now

```
 public List<HistoryLog> getAllHistoryLogsForListView(String imageName) {
        List<HistoryLog> historyLogList = new ArrayList<>();
        // Select All Query ORDER BY Timestamp | SORT ASC | LIMIT 150 rows

        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_HISTORY + " ORDER BY " + KEY_TIMESTAMP + " ASC " + " LIMIT 150";


        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.beginTransaction();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                HistoryLog historyLog = new HistoryLog();
                historyLog.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
                historyLog.setTimeStamp(cursor.getString(1));
                historyLog.setImageName(cursor.getString(2));

                // Adding history logs to list
                historyLogList.add(historyLog);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        db.endTransaction();

        // return history logs list
        return historyLogList;
    }
```

Comment: not clear what you want actually?

Comment: I want to know how many images has same name i need to count it

Answer (score 2):

Use [GROUP BY](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_group_by.htm):

```
SELECT imagename, count(*) FROM History GROUP BY imagename;
```

Then you can obtain count for each image from cursor:

```
final Map<Integer, Integer> imageCount = new HashMap<>();
// where key is imagename (int) and value is count (int)
if (c.moveToFirst()) {
    do {
        imageCount.put(
            c.getInt(0),
            c.getInt(1)
        );
    } while (c.moveToNext());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT IMAGE_NAME, COUNT(IMAGE_NAME) from HISTORY_TBL GROUP BY IMAGE_NAME